# Is there any way to handle a particular column while adding the rows dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am generating a dynamic table on click of a button as below -

```
 $('.addRowButton').click(function () {

            ++counter;
            var index=counter-1;
            var newRowHtml =
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + counter +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><input name="b2bProductList[' + index+ '].productId" class="variant b2bTableInput" /></td>' +
                '<td align="center"><span id="pvDetails" class="pvDetails"></span></td>' +
                '<td><div class="img48" style="vertical-align: top;"><img src=""></td>'+
                '<td><input name="b2bProductList[' + index + '].quantity" class="qty b2bTableInput"/></td>' +
                '<td align="center"><span id="mrp" class="mrp"/></td>' +
                '<td align="center"><input id="totalPrice" readonly="readonly" class="totalPrice b2bTableInput" type="text"></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#poTable').append(newRowHtml);
```

But I want to handle a particular column my self - kind of override it. I have to display an image and have to use some attributes in this column it which I can not put in the above code. How should I override it. If I am going to declare any `tr` or `td` in my table in the main `<table></table>` they are taking up extra row statically. Is there any particular way to handle a particular column while adding the rows dynamically?

EDIT - I have to set the source of the image, the source string of which I am fetching through an async call on the focusout of my `Id` textbox. Now can not set the source in the row generation time, so I will have to handle each column at a time giving `src` after I have fetched it. The column is mentioned in my code

```
'<td><div class="img48" style="vertical-align: top;"><img src=""></td>'+
```

Now I have to set the `src`. I hope this tells my problem clearly.

Comment: I dont understand your question properly as their is not enough information. Probably try to give that column a unique class or I'd and then after method finish generate another call to a seperate function to manipulate that existing column ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$('#myTable tr td::nth-child('+columnIndex+')')
```

if you know the index of the column or you could give that specific td a unique class

```
newRowHtml ='<tr>' + '<td class="someClass"></td> ... etc
```

and select that class:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(){
    // Some other code
});
```

Alternatively you could add the rows like so:

```
var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
var $id = $('<td></td>').html(id);
var $someOtherfield = $('<td></td>').html(someOtherData);

$('#myTable').append($row.append($id).append($someOtherfield));
```

then use the variable $someOtherfield to access it and work on it.

```
$someOtherfield.find('img').attr('src' , yourSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest to select the cells of a specific column, if you have no fancy colspan, is to use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) :

```
$('#mytable td:nth-child('+columnIndex+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tds= $('#poTable').find("td:first");
```

will give you the first column.

and to iterate over the elements

```
tds.each(function(index){
//do your stuff here..
});
```

hope this helps..

Comment: `$('#poTable').find("td:first");` will only return one `TD`, the first `TD` within the whole table